# Pylint error using lists as arguments in a function: Wrong handling indentation/bad-continuation. Cannot find out why

Tags: python, pylint, pep8

I have a question regarding Pylint. I'm receiving the error "Wrong handling indentation" with "bad-continuation". I would like to know what I'm doing wrong. I've tried reading PEP8 to keep aligned with the function parenthesis but it did not work. Here's what I've tried: Thanks!

```
WALLACE_SP1[i] = rad_intercpt_wallace(
                                      [[K_SPECIES1[i],
                                      LAI_SPECIES1[i],
                                      SP_HEIGHT[i]],
                                      [K_SPECIES2[i],
                                      LAI_SPECIES2[i],
                                      SP_HEIGHT[i]]])[0]

WALLACE_SP1[i] = rad_intercpt_wallace(
                                      [[K_SPECIES1[i],
                                      LAI_SPECIES1[i],
                                      SP_HEIGHT[i]],
                                      [K_SPECIES2[i],
                                      LAI_SPECIES2[i],
                                      SP_HEIGHT[i]]]
                                      )[0]

WALLACE_SP1[i] = rad_intercpt_wallace([[K_SPECIES1[i], LAI_SPECIES1[i],
                                      SP_HEIGHT[i]], [K_SPECIES2[i],
                                      LAI_SPECIES2[i], SP_HEIGHT[i]]])[0]

WALLACE_SP1[i] = rad_intercpt_wallace([[K_SPECIES1[i], LAI_SPECIES1[i],
                                        SP_HEIGHT[i]],
                                        [K_SPECIES2[i], LAI_SPECIES2[i],
                                         SP_HEIGHT[i]]])[0]
```

Comment: Note that pylint sometimes requires impossible things: x spaces, not enough indentation; x+1 spaces, too much indentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each interior `[` requires its own consistent indentation. For example, `LAI_SPECIES` must be aligned with `K_SPECIES` (since they are both part of the same list).

```
WALLACE_SP1[i] = rad_intercpt_wallace(
    [[K_SPECIES1[i],
      LAI_SPECIES1[i],
      SP_HEIGHT[i]],
     [K_SPECIES2[i],
      LAI_SPECIES2[i],
      SP_HEIGHT[i]]])[0]
```

In the alternative:

```
WALLACE_SP1[i] = rad_intercpt_wallace(
    [[K_SPECIES1[i], LAI_SPECIES1[i], SP_HEIGHT[i]],
     [K_SPECIES2[i], LAI_SPECIES2[i], SP_HEIGHT[i]]])[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the only way I've found for pep8 to stop complaining:

```
WALLACE_SP1[i] = rad_intercpt_wallace([[K_SPECIES1[i],
                                      LAI_SPECIES1[i],
                                      SP_HEIGHT[i]],
                                      [K_SPECIES2[i],
                                      LAI_SPECIES2[i],
                                      SP_HEIGHT[i]]])[0]

WALLACE_SP1[i] = rad_intercpt_wallace([[K_SPECIES1[i],
                                      LAI_SPECIES1[i],
                                      SP_HEIGHT[i]],
                                      [K_SPECIES2[i],
                                      LAI_SPECIES2[i],
                                      SP_HEIGHT[i]]]
                                      )[0]

WALLACE_SP1[i] = rad_intercpt_wallace([[K_SPECIES1[i], LAI_SPECIES1[i],
                                      SP_HEIGHT[i]], [K_SPECIES2[i],
                                      LAI_SPECIES2[i], SP_HEIGHT[i]]])[0]

WALLACE_SP1[i] = rad_intercpt_wallace([[K_SPECIES1[i],
                                      LAI_SPECIES1[i],
                                      SP_HEIGHT[i]],
                                      [K_SPECIES2[i],
                                      LAI_SPECIES2[i],
                                      SP_HEIGHT[i]]])[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

All (except for the second/last version by Robᵩ) above solutions seem unreadable to me.
This on the other hand is readable:

```
def rad_intercpt_wallace(arg):
    print arg

WALLACE_SP1[i] = rad_intercpt_wallace([
    [
        K_SPECIES1[i],
        LAI_SPECIES1[i],
        SP_HEIGHT[i]
    ],
    [
        K_SPECIES2[i],
        LAI_SPECIES2[i],
        SP_HEIGHT[i],
    ],
])[0]
```

And it seems `pep8` gives no warning. And `pylint` complaines only about:

```
No config file found, using default configuration
************* Module sample3
C:  1, 0: Missing module docstring (missing-docstring)
C:  1, 0: Missing function docstring (missing-docstring)
E:  4, 0: Undefined variable 'WALLACE_SP1' (undefined-variable)
E:  4,12: Undefined variable 'i' (undefined-variable)
E:  6, 8: Undefined variable 'K_SPECIES1' (undefined-variable)
E:  6,19: Undefined variable 'i' (undefined-variable)
E:  7, 8: Undefined variable 'LAI_SPECIES1' (undefined-variable)
E:  7,21: Undefined variable 'i' (undefined-variable)
E:  8, 8: Undefined variable 'SP_HEIGHT' (undefined-variable)
E:  8,18: Undefined variable 'i' (undefined-variable)
E: 11, 8: Undefined variable 'K_SPECIES2' (undefined-variable)
E: 11,19: Undefined variable 'i' (undefined-variable)
E: 12, 8: Undefined variable 'LAI_SPECIES2' (undefined-variable)
E: 12,21: Undefined variable 'i' (undefined-variable)
E: 13, 8: Undefined variable 'SP_HEIGHT' (undefined-variable)
E: 13,18: Undefined variable 'i' (undefined-variable)
```

And doesn't require incredibly long lines even if function name is long.